# Hibernate Error IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate, cascading-deletes

My `DELETE` query is failing.

**Here's my code:**

```
String q = "SELECT p.id FROM Person p, DomainGroup g WHERE 
   p member of g.coordinators" + " AND g.id = :groupId 
   AND p.id = :personId";

List<Long> test = getEntityManager()
  .createQuery(q).setParameter("groupId", followingId)
  .setParameter("personId", followerId).getResultList();

log.debug("test = " + test);

String deleteGroupCoordinatorQuery = 
  "DELETE FROM Person p, DomainGroup g WHERE p member 
     of g.coordinators" + " AND g.id = :groupId 
        AND p.id = :personId";

List<Long> test = getEntityManager()
      .createQuery(deleteGroupCoordinatorQuery).setParameter
      ("groupId", followingId)
      .setParameter("personId", followerId).executeUpdate();
```

**output:**

```
test = [1,2,3]

2012-10-26 13:44:56,437 ERROR org.company.commons.server.service.ServiceActionController - Error occurred performing transaction. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:280)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
```

Comment: might it have something to do with cascades?

Comment: @pengibot can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, was just thinking this could be the cause of it. Sounds like Steve's answer is the root of your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define multiple "query roots" (`Person p` and `DomainGroup g`), but a DELETE query can have only one such root.

You want something like:

```
delete Person p
where p.id in (
    select c.id
    from DomainGroup g
        join g.coordinators c
    where g.id = :groupId
      and c.id = :personId
)
```

or

```
delete Person p
where p.id = :personId
  and p.id in (
    select c.id
    from DomainGroup g
        join g.coordinators c
    where g.id = :groupId
)
```

Comment: should this work? "DELETE FROM DomainGroup g WHERE g.id = :groupId AND :personId member of g.coordinators"

Comment: That would delete DomainGroups.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I do not. I only want to remove the id of Person p, DomainGroup g where p.id is a member of g.coordinators.

Comment: That makes no sense.  Just "answer" my question by restating your invalid query isn't really an answer ;)  What do you mean "remove the id"?

Comment: Sorry about that. Let me explain as if I were using Postgres. I have a table, "group_coordinators." It has 2 columns: user_name and group_name. If a row read "kevin, stackoverflow" then it would mean that I'm an administrator for the group, stackoverflow. I would like to write a query that will remove this 'kevin|stackoverflow' row from the group_coordinators table. The @Entity DomainGroup has this entry,  @JoinTable(name = "Group_Coordinators").

Comment: Steve, I actually used a 'select' query to get the right DomainGroup. Then I used the Hibernate object, DomainGroup, to remove a Group Coordinator from DomainGroup.getCoordinators(). I could not delete a Group Coordinator since Group_Coordinator is not an entity. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `on delete cascade` feature then you should remove all references to the object before deleting it.